# Show different content before and after logged in

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to show different div with different contents in different condition.

If customer is logged in, then show content A,
If customer is not logged in, then show content B,

This is the script I have, not sure it is correct or not.

```php
<?php if (!$logged) {


$disp_div=1;

} else { 

$disp_div=0;

} ?>
```

This is the jQuery

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

var show=<?php echo $disp_div; ?>

 if(show==1)
 {
    $('#div_logged_in').show();
    $('#div_not_logged_in').hide();
   
 }
else if(show==0)
 {
    $('#div_logged_in').hide();
    $('#div_not_logged_in').show();
     }
 });
```

This is the HTML

```html
<div id="div_logged_in">
Content A
</div>

<div id="div_not_logged_in">
Content B
</div>
```

Comment: You are aware of that the content will be visible in the html source code anyway?

Comment: yup, I aware of that.

I'm a graphic designer and trying to learn programming myself. 

Before going to deeper programming knowledge, the only way for me is to use every method I could found and could understand easily. 

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**A: Why !$logged is wrong:**

You use a local variable. Next time your user refreshes the page he won't be logged in anymore. For that you can store variables in a array called $_SESSION . This array is saved for a client session on you webserver. As longs as the user stays there it will always remain the same (until YOU change it). For that you need a session_start(); in the first line of you main PHP script.

**B: Why the javascript part is a security leak:**

Your website is designed not to filter the content that is sended to the user. Every user gets the whole content, just the visibility is changed. In this way every advanced user can just look into your code and see all the secrets you want to hide.

**C: What is the right way?**

It just some PHP that echos HTML without Javascript and uses $_SESSION:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == "yes") { //You have to set that somewhere else just like $logged
    ?>
        <p> You ARE logged in. </p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p> You ARE NOT logged in. </p>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: good answer, its better to use if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == 'value')

Comment: You're right. In my own websites I am used to just set $_SESSION["UID"] so I check ($_SESSION["UID"] != "").

Comment: I understand of the leak, but currently I'm barely have programming knowledge, so I just use the way that easier for me to understand.

Thanks for the correction, I'll try to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is `$logged`. If it is the variable to find whether the user is logged in, then your condition is just opposite of your requirement. You are showing `div_logged_in` when the user is not logged in from this condition.

```
if(show==1)
 {
    $('#div_logged_in').show();
    $('#div_not_logged_in').hide();

 }
```

The value of show will be 1 when `$logged` is false. So change the condition and you will get it. In this scenario, i would suggest you to go with **SESSIONS**. You can use anywhere to check whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: do you depend on client-side for controlling secure content?

Comment: @AkamOmer I don't depend on client-side script for these conditions. Please read my last line. I have suggested him to go with Sessions only.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to start reading about [sessions and the $_SESSION superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

After that, throw that script away, and look for a proper tutorial, I found a very nice one here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/a-better-login-system/ - though it may be a bit advanced since it talks about ACL, which you probably won't need.

But if you can try and understand the rest of the tutorial, you should be fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please do not depend on client-side validation because its a security flow within your application, what if the customer viewed the source code for your page? then they see hidden contents.

Your approach is correct but you have to use $_SESSION or $_COOKIE not if (!$logged) and as I said, do not out put the content totally.

Answer (score 0):

use
 `if($_SESSION["username"])`

you can set it in the login.php file
and destroy it by using session_destroy() on the logout.php